# Instagram API attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, social-networking, instagram

Im new to using the Instagram API, I was just wondering does any know any of the attributed tags that would be used to display comments, or to display location of an image. Below you can see that I'm able to retrieve the link, a low resolution image, profile_picture and the like count. Can anyone provide any others that I could use to get as much information as possible about an image.

```
$(".pics").append("<div class='paul'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +
        "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"'></img></a>" + "<img class='sam' src='" + data.data[i].user.profile_picture + "'></img><div class='like'>"+ data.data[i].likes.count + " likes</div></div>");
```

Comment: Use `console.log(data.data[i])` to explore the object and see all its data.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go here and check the response of a media API call and check the data:
http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

Here are some other data you can get for a photo:

Location:

```
data.data[i].location.latitude
data.data[i].location.longitude
```

Comments:

```
data.data[i].comments.data[j].text
```

Caption on Photo:

```
data.data[i].caption
```

Users in photo

```
data.data[i]. users_in_photo
```

...